# Array[n] vs Array[10] - Initializing array with variable vs numeric literal

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, size

I am having the following issue with my code:

```
int n = 10;
double tenorData[n]   =   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Returns the following error:

```
error: variable-sized object 'tenorData' may not be initialized
```

Whereas using `double tenorData[10]` works.

Anyone know why?

Comment: It would help to give a language. In C++ your arrays of that form need to have a compile-time constant size.

Comment: C++, using Codeblocks with the mingw32-g++ compiler!

Comment: Thanks, Justin and @AndrewVarnerin, that solved it!

added const before the int:

    const int n = 10;

Solved!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 256, accepted):

In C++, variable length arrays are not legal. G++ allows this as an "extension" (because C allows it), so in G++ (without being `-pedantic` about following the C++ standard), you can do:

```
int n = 10;
double a[n]; // Legal in g++ (with extensions), illegal in proper C++
```

If you want a "variable length array" (better called a "dynamically sized array" in C++, since proper variable length arrays aren't allowed), you either have to dynamically allocate memory yourself:

```
int n = 10;
double* a = new double[n]; // Don't forget to delete [] a; when you're done!
```

Or, better yet, use a standard container:

```
int n = 10;
std::vector<double> a(n); // Don't forget to #include <vector>
```

If you still want a proper array, you can use a *constant*, not a *variable*, when creating it:

```
const int n = 10;
double a[n]; // now valid, since n isn't a variable (it's a compile time constant)
```

Similarly, if you want to get the size from a function in C++11, you can use a `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int n()
{
    return 10;
}

double a[n()]; // n() is a compile time constant expression
```

Comment: Thank you, this is another good solution. What I really need in the end is a vector rather than an array!

Comment: @msmf14: Yeah, standard containers, like `vector`, are incredibly useful.

Comment: Does the vector solution initialize each element when you call "std::vector<[some class]> a(n);"?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, it value-intializes (or default-constructs for `struct`s/`class`es) the elements (so `int`s/`float`s/etc will all be zero).

Comment: If you're not allocating much (if it's small compared to stack size), I'd prefer using stack memory with alloca(3) and placement new. This way you don't need to worry about free'ing the memory, and memory allocation is much much faster.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that g++ allows it. Because I did not observe this error and this explains the difference.

Comment: Thnx. A nice range of alternatives.

Comment: you say that g++ allows it, but it is not proper c++. My question is how would you compile proper c++?

Comment: Quick question, why this  `std::vector<double, n> a;` does not work? In my code snippet `int size{};
    cin >> size;
    vector <int, size> arr;` gives an error but `int size{};
    cin >> size;
    vector <int> arr(size);` this works. Why?