# Why does this c++ program compile?

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation

It is my understanding that the c++ compiler will not allow you to initialize an array with a variable yet this program compiles and runs on my computer, why is that?

```
// this should not compile because there is a variable in the array declaration

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int ar[x];
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Some of them have an extension for *variable-length arrays.*

Comment: @fred  It means that the compiler has its own language extensions that allow to use VLAs. You should switch them off to get a compiler error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C++, variable length arrays are not legal. G++ allows this as an
>   "extension" (because C allows it), so in G++ you can do this.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) / [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number/15013295) further.

Comment: note: g++ allowed this extension before C allowed it

Comment: @M.M.: yes true. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score -2):

The size of the array may not be a variable.

Comment: OP doesn't want to know whether it's allowed by the standard--they *already* know it's not allowed. They want to know why the compiler is letting them.