# Create an input array of 10 ints by reading values from the user

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, sizeof

I am trying the following code :

```
int main() {
    int x[10] ;
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5} ;
    int n ;
    int b[n] ;
    //int c[] ; gives compilation error

    cout<<sizeof(x)<<endl ; //prints 40
    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl ; //prints 20
    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl ; //prints 4
}
```

Now my question is what exactly happens when I define `b`.
I have tried to read answers to similar questions but I did not get a satisfactory reply.
Because arrays are created statically, so there size must be given at the time of declaring them. Then why is declaration of `b` valid. Does the `sizeof(b)` indicate that this just treated as a `int pointer`

Comment: default value of int is zero that is why it is valid.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not part of the C++ standard. This is not a static array.

Comment: @VikramSingh: Default value of int is garbage. **NOT** 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array\[n\] vs Array\[10\] - Initializing array with variable vs real number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number)

Comment: `int b[n];` is also a compilation error

Comment: how is the title related to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what exactly happens
>
> ```
> int n ;
> int b[n] ;
> ```

Using the value of uninitialized integer (except the narrow character type) has undefined behaviour (*UB*). Furthermore, since `n` is not a compile time constant, but is used as a size of an array, the program is ill-formed according to the C++ standard (this means that the compiler is allowed to refuse to compile the program, and is required to at least show a diagnostic message).

However, if your compiler supports variable length arrays (*VLA*, a language extension), then *exactly what happens* depends on how the compiler has implemented VLA (and of course, how it happens to deal with the UB that you introduced).

> Then why is declaration of `b` valid.

It is in fact, *not* valid in standard C++.

> Does the `sizeof(b)` indicate that this just treated as a `int` pointer

No. Since the behaviour is undefined, the output indicates nothing. Even if the size of `int` pointer happens to be 4 on your system, the output happens to be the same only by chance.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, variable length arrays are not allowed, arrays have to be fixed size, if you want to allocate size dynamically you may want to use `malloc` and allocate memory mannually. However, the default value of `int` serves the purpose here. I won't recommend this practice though as it may yield undefined behaviour. Read these links [Array[n] vs Array[10] - Initializing array with variable vs real number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number) and [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) they have some good explanations.

Comment: `However, the default value of int serves the purpose here.` But there is no default value of int in this question's code, there is a random value of int `n`

Answer (score 0):

First, `int b[n]` is not a valid C++ code, unless `n` is a constant expression. You get away with it only because you use GCC, and it is permitted as an extension (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length).

Second, to check what is going on, let us see this:

My program var-arr.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m=0, n=5, k;
    int a[m], b[n], c[k];
    cout
    << "sizeof(a)=" << sizeof(a)
    << " sizeof(b)=" << sizeof(b)
    << " sizeof(c)=" << sizeof(c)
    << endl;
}
```

Here is what happens when I compile and run it (`[~/CPP]` is the prompt)

```
[~/CPP] g++ -o var-arr var-arr.cpp
[~/CPP] ./var-arr
sizeof(a)=0 sizeof(b)=20 sizeof(c)=0
```

Some time later

```
[~/CPP] ./var-arr
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What does it mean?  It means that when you write `int n;` within a function, `n` remains uninitialized.  So when you write `int a[n];` after it, the length of `a` can be ANYTHING AT ALL.  It also can be too big to allocate `a`.