# Copy part of array and pass to constructor

Tags: c++

I have an array `char buffer[]`. What I want to do, is to copy values from `buffer` from `foundSecondComma+1` to `foundSecondComma+1+dataLen`.

Next, I want to creat object `Answer a` and pass to constructor few data with part of `buffer`.

```
// here extracted buffer will be stored
char contentData[dataLen];

// extract data from buffer
copy(buffer + foundSecondComma+1, buffer+foundSecondComma+1+dataLen, contentData);

//create new object and push to list
Answer a(dataLen, header, contentData);
answers.push_back(a);
```

And this is my `Answer` class:

```
Answer::Answer(int dataLen, string header, char* content) {
    this->dataLen = dataLen;
    this->header = header;

    this->content = new char[strlen(content)+1];
    strcpy(this->content, content);
}
```

So for some reason `a.content` stores different data than part of `buffer`. This simple loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.dataLen; i++)
{
    printf("buffer[%d]=%c  a.content[%d]=%c\n", i, buffer[foundSecondComma+1+i], i, a.content[i]);
}
```

Is showing, that values are not the same. Where I make mistake? I am using `g++` to compile program.

Comment: From the context, I assume that `dataLen` is not a compile time constant. In that case, `char contentData[dataLen];` is not standard c++. It uses an extension known as variable length arrays. Some compilers like gcc support it by default, but it's not portable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've read that I can use this in `g++`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013295/9249024

Comment: It's not wrong to use them, but you should prefer portable alternatives such as `std::vector`. Though on Stack Overflow, unless otherwise specified, c++ code is expected to be standard conforming.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `contentData` is null terminated, meaning it wouldn't be a string. Passing it to `strcpy` would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Could you put the declarations for the member variables of your Answer class?