# I can't have variable as size when I'm declaring the array?

Tags: c++

So I have 2 dimensional array called char Screen[50][5];
When I declare it like this -> char Screen[50][5]; everything works.
But when I put variables in square brackets instead of numbers I get the error saying Screen isn't declared.

I've tried this method of declaring char[][] Screen = new char[ScreenWidth][ScreenHeight]; too

```cpp
int ScreenWidth = 50;
int ScreenHeight = 5;
char Screen[ScreenWidth][ScreenHeight];
```

[Error] 'Screen' was not declared in this scope

Comment: `const int ScreenWidth = 50;
const int ScreenHeight = 5;` VLA's aren't valid standard c++ syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not related to you using variables for array sizes, however, this is not possible, C-Style array sizes have to be known at compiletime.

Your error is that you use Screen somewhere else, but this line errors, so Screen never gets defined.

Use the `constexpr` keyword for your variables, and it's possible

```cpp
constexpr int ScreenWidth = 50;
constexpr int ScreenHeight = 5;
char Screen[ScreenWidth][ScreenHeight];
```

EDIT:
You might be able to mark it `const` instead of `constexpr`, the compiler will most likely optimize that, but you can't rely on that.