# Text appearing more than once

Tags: c++

so I am trying to come up with a firefighting system for my science fair project and one of the main things that come with trying to do so is the coding.  it is still in the early stages but for the final product of what I have so far, the code is unnecessarily repeating itself, and I don't know how to stop it.  this is the code, so please, if you answer it, paste the fixed code and tell me what is wrong so I don't run into it later.  code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int ave = 0;
   int num;
   //begins ave and basic info being collected
   cout << "how many sensors will there be: " << endl;
   cin >> num;

   int sen[num];
   cout << "enter the heat on the sensors in order: " << endl;
   for( int i=0; i<num; i++ ){
      cin >> sen[i];
      ave = ave + sen[i];
   }

   ave = ave / num;
   cout << ave << endl;
   //end of basic info/average
   bool sens[num];
   for( int i=0; i<num; i++ ){
      if( sen[i] + 60 > ave ){
         sens[i] = 1;
      }
   }

   for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
      if( sens[i] == 1 ){
         cout << "there is a fire at sensor" << sens[i] << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code a little bit. It is barely readable as it is now

Comment: in what way do you mean, space out the code?

Comment: the code indentation is wrong making you code very hard to read.

Comment: I don't know how to change the code aspect of it, but please, just run it in something and let me know what to change, I haven't written this language of code in a while, and even then I learned it for 5 months in 7th grade.  so putting it bluntly, I am bad at c++

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us any error logs, we can only guess what went wrong, but I see one thing and I'll explain.

---

> C++ standard (till C++11) doesn’t support variable sized arrays.

You can't use

```
cin >> num;
int sen[num];
```

You can use:

```
cin >> num;
int* sen = new int[num];
```

More info here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number#answer-15013295).

---

In your code change `int sen[num];` for  `int* sen = new int[num];`
and change `bool sens[num];` for `bool* sens = new bool[num];`

Comment: Please explain it like as if I were a 5-year-old, I really don't know very much about C++, I forgot everything but the bare basics, and only got back into it for my project

Comment: also, my lord and savior Gaben, bring a heavy update to TF2

Comment: You must define arrays in a different fashion. In C++ you can't make array the size of "variable" (the size that changes, or is from input). Hovewer you can get the same utilities with "pointers" (my second block of code).

Comment: The code executes two times, or does it fall into "never ending loop"?