# Initialized a pointer array in C - Variable sized object may not be initialized

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, initialization

I was trying to initialise a array made by pointer:

the code I used was:

```
int c = 15;
Struct *Pointer[c] = {NULL};
```

but C give me a error message which says:

```
"message": "variable-sized object may not be initialized",
```

but when I change my code to:

```
Struct *Pointer[15] = {NULL};
```

it worked!

Is there any way to fix it? I can't use 15 instead of variable "c"

Cheers!

Comment: Like it says, if the array size isn't constant you can't use an initializer.  You'll have to write a loop: `for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) Pointer[i]=NULL;`.  Or use `memset` if your platform has NULL pointers as all-bits-zero (most do).

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks Nate - I tried memset, it worked!! Thank you - One thing I do not understand, even if I made C as Const int, it still doesn't work. Is that normal.?

Comment: Yes, that's normal.  Just part of the somewhat peculiar way that C treats `const`.  C++ is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable length arrays may not be initialized in their declarations.

You can use the standard string function `memset` to initialize the memory occupied by a variable length array.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int c = 15;
Struct *Pointer[c];

memset( Pointer, 0, c * sizeof( *Pointer ) );
```

Pay attention to that variable length arrays shall have automatic storage duration that is they may be declared in a function and may not have the storage specifier `static`.

Comment: Hey Vlad - I think you are right - By using memset(), it somehow initialized another array....is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: @leo: That won't happen if you use `memset` correctly, so you must have a bug somewhere.  You could ask it as a new question, but be sure to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a loop to initialize the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    Pointer[i] = NULL; // set all of these values to NULL
```

Now, `Pointer` will be of size `c`.

Also, this link may help, too: [Array[n] vs Array[10] - Initializing array with variable vs real number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013077/arrayn-vs-array10-initializing-array-with-variable-vs-real-number)