# How do I read in a string and transfer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, cin

In this c++ code, I am taking a string from `std::cin` and transferring each `char` item into a `char` array.

```
int length; // length of the string
cin >> length;

char charList[length]; // list of the characters
string sequence; // string sequence
cin >> sequence;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    charList[i] = sequence[i];
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this or if I am getting something wrong. Are the items out of the indexed string `char` or `string` type?

Comment: Why? It always works when I'm using `int` so why won't it work for `char` type?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why do you ask for the length instead of using `sequence.length()`. Also remember that `cin >>` stops reading at the first space.

Comment: The code is supposed to take a string, put the first character into the first item in charList, same for the rest.

Comment: The length is problematic because the length of the `sequence` may be different from the  length variable which could cause undefined behavior and there really is not a need to ask the user for the lenght.

Comment: No, here you always have to enter the length of the string.

Comment: I am also not using this for a user interface.

Comment: I don't think the assignment wants you to use a std::string at all if you have to read x characters into an array.

Comment: It does. I checked.

Comment: You may want to change `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {` to `for (int i = 0; i < std::min(length,sequence.length()); i++) {`  to make sure you don't go out of bounds on the string.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Don't forget to reserve an extra slot in the array for the null terminator.

Comment: Note: What if there are spaces in the input string? `>>`  stops as soon as it sees any whitespace.

Comment: in this case the input string does not have whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to answer your doubt about the type: `sequence[i]` is of type `char`.

Next, concerning your implementation: to start with, as many people have suggested in the comments, I recommend not getting the length of the string separately from the string itself, because the length of the input string may be different from the declared length, and this may cause all sort of problems (ever heard of the infamous bug [heartbleed](https://xkcd.com/1354/)?)

So, this is the minimum I would do:

```cpp
  string sequence; // string sequence
  cin >> sequence;
  char charList[sequence.length()]; // list of the characters
  for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) {
      charList[i] = sequence[i];
  }
```

However, this is still not satisfactorily enough because the above code is not conformant. In other words it is not valid C++ because C++ does not really allow variable-length arrays. Depending on the compiler you may get away with it, for instance g++ accepts it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013295/12175820

But even with g++, if you compile with the `-pedantic` flag you'll get the following warning:

```
str2arr.cpp:10:8: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘charList’ [-Wvla]
   10 |   char charList[sequence.length()]; // list of the characters
```

which compounded to `-Werror` gives a full-blown compilation error:

```
str2arr.cpp:10:8: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘charList’ [-Werror=vla]
   10 |   char charList[sequence.length()]; // list of the characters
```

Plus you might have trouble with more advanced usage, for instance I've just discovered that `typeid(charList)` won't compile with a variable-length array...

So the *real* way to do this in C++ would be using pointers and dynamic-memory allocation, in the heap, using operator `new`:

```cpp
  string sequence; // string sequence
  cin >> sequence;
  char* charList = new char[sequence.length()]; // list of the characters
  for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) {
      charList[i] = sequence[i];
  }
```

the above code is valid C++ accepted by any compiler.

Comment: Thank you, that works very well.